# disable flash in selenium cross browser

Tags: c#, flash

I want to use selenium to disable flash in IE, firefox, and chrome.

is there a way to do it cross browser, and if there isn't, is there a command you know for one of them or all?

(I am using C#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Firefox, you can try this (in Java):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("plugin.state.flash", 0);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676369/how-to-disable-flash-in-selenium-remote-webdriver/18944625#18944625).