# Firefox driver becomes unresponsive when flash is loaded

Tags: flash, firefox, selenium, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I am using Selenium grid 2.40 with Firefox (V27.0.1) remote driver that runs in windows 7. I also use C# API. When flash is loaded in the page Firefox remote driver takes 3 to 4 times more to respond, to the point that I have to first try to remove flash object from the page before I can continue with the test. Does anybody have the same issue and had a better fix than removing flash?

I don't have the same issue with local webdriver.

Comment: Would it be an option to disable flash through desired capabilities?

Comment: better way for sure! Thanks!

Comment: Just in case, here are the relevant threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676369/how-to-disable-flash-in-selenium-remote-webdriver and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406719/how-to-disable-flash-in-firefox-with-selenium-in-python.